# Can we use subfigure option using figure* environment. I want to place two figures side by side in two column paper and I want to use subfigure option

Tags: floats, two-column

I read that for spanning two columns we use figure* environment. But using figure* we find it difficult to control the placement of figures while compiling PDF. Can I use figure environment for this purpose? What will be the best option to do this that is also helpful in controlling their placement?

```
 `\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}  %For writing \mathbb{R}
\usepackage{mathrsfs} %for \mathscr

\usepackage{grffile} % deals with extension .PNG problems

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{figure}%
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=0.7\columnwidth]{Archi.png}]
    \end{subfigure}
    \hspace{0.05\textwidth}
    \begin{subfigure}{.49\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{W.png}%
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `figure*` is exactly `figure` but configured to span both columns so your question is entirely unclear. The answer would seem to be "use `figure*` If you get errors using that provide a complete small test document that shows the error (use `example-image` as the image so people can test the example.

Comment: unrelated but your horizontal widths seem inconsistent, you have .49+.05+.49 \columnwidth which is already more than column width plus you have a word space either side of the `\hspace` so an additional .6em usually.

Comment: So if the figure* environment is same as figure. Does it mean can I use figure instead of figure* to span the two columns. I want to place two figures side by side spanning two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked in a follow-up comment,

> Does it mean can I use `figure` instead of `figure*` to span the two columns?

Short answer: No. Longer answer: No. Very long answer: No.

To place two graphs side by side within a single `figure*` environment, encase the graphs (along with their `\caption` statements) in separate `minipage` environments. I further suggest you use width `\columnwidth` for the `minipage` environments and separate them horizontally with an `\hspace{\fill}` directive.

By the way, the `caption` and `subcaption` packages don't work well with the `revtex` document classes.

[image]

```
\documentclass[aps,twocolumn,secnumarabic,nobalancelastpage]{revtex4}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove "demo" option in real document

%\usepackage{subcaption} % not recommended for revtex4 doc. class

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Archi.png}
        \caption{Left-hand figure}
    \end{minipage}%
    \hspace{\fill}
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{W.png}
        \caption{Right-hand figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes i tried this code and worked.thanks.can you please explain that in minipage you used columnwidth and in includegraphic option you used textwidth. How this options effect? Why we don't use same option at both places?

Comment: @jerry - The length parameter `\textwidth` adjusts dynamically to where it occurs. Inside a `minipage` of whatever width, the full available width is `\textwidth`, and that's what the code uses to set the width of the graph.